# iPhone-Move UI Image view along a Bezier curve path

Tags: ios

I want o move the UIImageView along a Bezier path, can anybody point me towards from where i can learn and achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exact answer to that is probably very hard to do. But you may get close to what you want by using two CALayers, one a sublayer of the other. Put a x-translation animation on the one layer, and an y-translation animation on the other. Then experiment with custom animation timing functions for each of the translations.
See [Animations Types and Timing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006670-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the response. i was able to achieve